# read NSUserNotification display style

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsusernotification, system-preferences

I am implementing an application that displays notifications using NSUserNotificationCenter. Everything works fine by now.

I have added NSUserNotificationAlertStyle key with alert in the plist so I get the default selection to alert style.

However I couldn't find a way to check the user selection in system preferences notificaion center. Based on that information I must perform certain tasks in my application

**Is there a way to get the delivered notificaion style or the user selection from system preferences?**

Comment: I spent some time hunting but Apple sure doesn't make it easy.  Some of the notification center prefs are kept in the "`com.apple.notificationcenterui`" files, which you can see by typing in "`defaults read com.apple.notificationcenterui`" and "`defaults -currentHost read com.apple.notificationcenterui`" at the Terminal prompt.